# CreateJS with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, createjs, .d.ts

I have these errors and not sure how to fix it. Every time I try to compile my project with TSC, it will throw errors:

`error TS2339: Property 'call' does not exist on type 'void'`

on this line of code (**call** method):

```
createjs.Tween.get(this.clip).wait(this.clipDuration).call(this.endFrameScript.bind(this));
```

and this error

`error TS2339: Property 'to' does not exist on type 'void'`

on this line (**to** method)

`createjs.Tween.get(this.feedback).wait(1000).to({alpha:0},1000);`

What is the best way to rewrite these lines of code so it will conform to Typescript? And where can we find the most up-to-date CreateJS d.ts file? The CreateJS d.ts (easeljs.d.ts) posted on DefinitelyTyped GitHub has too many errors.

Thanks